# Pass variable to @AndroidFindBy Annotation using Java

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to pass variable to @AndroidFindBy annotation value, however it only allows constant variables.

For example code looks like below:

```
@iOSFindBy(accessibility = "Settings")
@AndroidFindBy(id = "Settings")
public MobileElement SettingsButton;

@iOSFindBy(accessibility = "Contacts")
@AndroidFindBy(id = "Contacts")
public MobileElement ContactsButton;
```

How I want to change is to use non constant variable or any function that returns string, instead of final static variable as below:

```
@iOSFindBy(accessibility = Funct(String1))
@AndroidFindBy(id = Funct(String1))
public MobileElement SettingsButton;

@iOSFindBy(accessibility = Funct(String2))
@AndroidFindBy(id = Funct(String2))
public MobileElement ContactsButton;
```

It would be great if you could share any idea or suggestions regarding this issue.

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold, this is a common question.  You cannot use variables in annotated page factory locators, they must be known at compile-time and therefore must be constants/literals.  The only "work-around" that I use is to define an entire array and then write a custom method inside the page object to select a specific element within that array.

Comment: @Random - you can use it like this in java
`public static final String class_name= "something";`
`@AndroidFindBy(className = class_name);`

Comment: you can use **accessibility**, **id** or **xpath** with @AndroidFindBy. For example: <br/>@AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "your accessibility id") <br/>  private MobileElement someElement;